# Menu para mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou a fazer um site para a empresa onde trabalho e fiz um menu multilevel.
O meu problema é que quando abro um dos niveis, o ultimo item não aparece e quando faço scroll o que mexe é a página que está atrás.
Queria saber o que estou a fazer de errado, será o position: fixed que coloquei na class?

```css
/*== RESET ==*/
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 font-weight: 300;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

body{
  background-color: #fff;
}

a {text-decoration: none;}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}


/*== CABEÇAHO ==*/
.cabecalho {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 padding: 3% 5%;
}

.logo {
 width: 70px;
 height: 91px;
 float: left;
 background: url(../_img/Estores_JF-mobile.jpg) center center/70px no-repeat;
 font-size: 0;
}

.btn-menu {
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 float: right;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 70px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #025aa4, #2599fb);
 color: #fff;
 box-shadow: 2px 3px 20px #888888;
}


/* == MENU == */
.menu {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: rgba(2, 90, 164, 0.9);
 top: 0;
 left: 0; 
}

.btn-close {
 float: right;
 font-size: 30pt;
 color: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 5%;
}

.menu ul {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
}

.menu li{
 padding: 4%;
}

.menu li a {
 font-size: 25pt;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 2%;
}

.menu li a:hover {
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

.submenu_prod {
 display: none;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 20%;
}

.submenu_prod li a{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 15pt;
}

.submenu_empr {
 display: none;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 20%;
}

.submenu_empr li a{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 15pt;
}













/* == BANNER == */
.banner {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 3% 4%;
 background: url(../_img/wallpaper-azul_web.jpg);
}

.title {
 width: 100%;
}

.title h1 {
 font-size: 35pt;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.title h2 {
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 18pt;
 color: #fff;
}

.buttons {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 5%;
}

.btn-sobre i {
 float: right;
}

.btn-sobre {
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 text-align: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 5%;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 color:#130400;
}





/* == SERVIÇOS == */
.servicos {
 margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
 float: left;
 padding: 3% 4%;
}

.servico {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff; 
 text-align: left;
 border-radius: 7px;
 margin-bottom: 3%; 
 text-align: center;
 box-shadow: 2px 3px 20px #888888;
}

.servico img {
 margin-top: 3%;
 border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0;
}

.inner {
 padding: 5%;
}

.inner a {
 font-size: 25pt;
 color: #130400;
 font-weight: 700;
 line-height: 1em;
}

.inner h4 {
 font-size: 18pt;
 margin-top: 2%;
 color: #130400;
}

.inner p {
 margin-top: 10%;
 color: #130400;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-pt">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Estores JF</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="description" content="Empresa especializada em fabrico de estores e redes mosquiteiras.">
 <meta name="keywords" content="Estore, Estores, Rede mosquiteira, Redes mosquiteiras, persianas">
 <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
 <meta name="author" content="Diogo Sousa">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="icon" href="_img/Estores_JF.png">
</head>
<body>


  <!-- CABEÇALHO -->
  <header class="cabecalho">
   <a href="index.html"><h1 class="logo">Estores JF - Empresa especializada em fabrico de estores</h1></a>

   <button class="btn-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </button>

   <nav class="menu">
    <a class="btn-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li class="sub_empr"><a href="#">A Empresa +</a></li>
        <ul class="submenu_empr">
         <li><a href="#">Quem Somos?</a></li>
        </ul>
       <li class="sub_prod"><a href="#">Produtos +</a></li>
       <ul class="submenu_prod">
         <li><a href="">Soluções Exteriores</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Soluções Interiores</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Portões e Grades</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Caixas Compactas</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Caixas Pré-reboco</a></li>
             <li><a href="">Motores e Comandos</a></li>
          </ul>
       <li><a href="contacto.html">Contactos</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>

  <!--BANNER-->
  <div class="banner">
    <div class="title">
     <hgroup>
      <h1>Estores - JF</h1>
      <h2>Possuimos o que precisa para o seu lar se tornar um
      lugar mais agradável.</h2>
     </hgroup>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
     <button class="btn-sobre"> Sobre <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--ARTIGOS-->
  <main class="servicos">
   <article class="servico">
    <a href="#"><img src="_img/Servicos-Mobile.jpg" alt="Serviços"></a>
    <div class="inner">
     <a href="#">Os nossos serviços!</a>
     <h4>Conheça-nos melhor...</h4>
     <p>Aqui fica o texto que explica o que fazemos, o que podemos fazer pelas pessoas!</p>
    </div>
   </article>
   <article class="servico">
    <a href="#"><img src="_img/termico-mobile.png" alt="Serviços"></a>
    <div class="inner">
     <a href="#">Estores</a>
     <h4>Temos o melhor para si!</h4>
     <p>sdaklndalndaklsndklsandklskldnsada
      lsandlkandlknlknda
     ndlkandklankldndsalnasdlnsa
     dnlkasndlkasndkaln</p>
    </div>
   </article>
   <article class="servico">
    <a href="#"><img src="_img/rede-mobile.jpg" alt="Serviços"></a>
    <div class="inner">
     <a href="#">Rede Mosquiteiras</a>
     <h4>Contra os mosquitos.</h4>
     <p>Aqui esplicar um pouco a função da rede mosquiteira.</p>
    </div>
   </article>
  </main>

  <footer></footer>
  



</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"></script>﻿  
  <script>

   /*Para aparecer o menu*/
   $(".btn-menu").click(function(){
   $(".menu").show();
  });
   /* para fechar o menu*/ 
   $(".btn-close").click(function(){
   $(".menu").hide();

  });
   /*para abrir sub menu produtos*/
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".sub_prod").click(function(e){
    $(".submenu_prod").toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
   })
  })
   /*para abrir sub menu empresa*/
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".sub_empr").click(function(e){
    $(".submenu_empr").toggle();
    e.preventDefault();
   })
  })
  </script>

</html>
```

[image: imagem]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber como fazer, para que no telmóvel não aconteça e consiga deslizar o menu para cima para clicar nos contactos.

Comment: basta colocar um max-height no `html,body` de `100%`, após isso, configurar um max-height na lista, e então um `overflow:auto`, caso ninguém tenha colocado uma resposta, assim que eu chegar em casa crio um fiddle pra explicar melhor :D

Comment: Muito obrigado @Murilo Gambôa, ainda ninguém respondeu, vou aguardar então. Mais uma vez obrigado

Comment: É isso mesmo. A altura do menu é maior que a área do navegador, por isso que parte dele fica fora de visão da tela. Quando vc faz um scroll, vai rolar a página toda e não o menu, pq o menu não tem scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução prática é adicionar um `overflow-y: auto;` na classe `.menu`, ficando assim:

```
.menu {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(2, 90, 164, 0.9);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto; /* irá gerar scroll vertical caso a altura ultrapasse a área da tela */
}
```

Comment: Se estiver depois a ver num telemóvel vai dar para andar para cima e para baixo o menu? Faz-me um pouco de confusão porque depois supostamente não terá o scroll certo?

Comment: Sim, testei no devtools do navegador e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: funciona perfeito, no caso, lembrando que quando o menu é rolado, e após ele ter rolado completamente em uma posição, então a página começa a rolar por trás do menu

Comment: @MuriloGambôa Sim. É possível fazer com que a página por trás não role tirando o scroll dela enquanto o menu estiver aberto, mas acho isso desnecessário.

Comment: @Dvdsamm  exato, é desnecessário, mas foi apenas uma observação :D